# Installation Error When Installing Git on Windows 10

Tags: git

I'm getting this below error when trying to install the Git-2.30.1-64-bit.exe.

[image: Git Installation Error]

Request you all to help in fixing this issue. OS is windows 10.

Comment: Let's clarify that Git != Github, Git is the *tool* and Github is the *platform* for Git repos. When you say "install the Github desktop version", do you mean [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) or the [Github Desktop app](https://desktop.github.com/)?

Comment: Yes.. my bad. I downloaded the Git from this URL: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: Then that's Git, not Github.

Comment: Yes.. I just want to stick with Git for now. But this error is blocking in completing the Git installation.

Comment: @VijayC have you found the solution. This is happening with me in 2023. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

This could be linked to [issue 1400](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1400#issuecomment-357785782) and [issue 1554](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1554#issuecomment-373142422):

Check the status of the [Null service](http://revertservice.com/10/null/)

```
sc query null
```

As a workaround, you could uncompress the latest [portable archive `PortableGit-2.30.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.30.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.30.1-64-bit.7z.exe), and check if Git is working through that "installation".